# get user's retweets and mention of one month

Tags: twitter

I could get users retweets and mention, but could not figure out how to get result for one month.

https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/mentions_timeline.json

And

I am using php to find the number of retweets a status has gotten.

this is my current code:

```
//get account info

$connection->request('GET',$connection->url('1.1/statuses/retweets'),
array('id'=> '363332903113351168'));

//get http response code for request

$response_code = $connection->response['code'];

//convert the json response to an array

$response_data = json_decode($connection->response['response'],true);

if($code != 200)
{
    print"ERROR: $response_code\n";
}
print_r($response_data);
```

To get mention and retweets.
Can someone tell me how retweet n mention result can shown for one month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try impliment this logic.
First to make filter by ID of tweets and next step filter by "created_at" field. After you will can retweets resalt.